# Serialize Django Request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'd like to serialize the Django request in order to log it in a DB. I tried different approaches but none of them successfully.

```
class RunTest(View):
  def get(self, request, url):
     srd = serializers.serialize('json', request)
     return HttpResponse(json.dumps(request.META))
```

But this raise the error

```
module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'serialize'
```

Probably because I'm using the rest-framework as a Middleware.
I also used

```
srd = json.dumps(request)
```

In this case the error is

```
Object of type 'WSGIRequest' is not JSON serializable
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? `vars(request)` maybe?

Comment: I want to save it in a DB, since I want to build a proxy that log all the requests and responses

Comment: What do you want to do with these data after you saved it into DB? Nothing? Will you ever use it?

Comment: from django.core import serializers

Comment: Just display to the user

Comment: @MohitHarshan is what I did in the first part with serializers.serialize

Comment: So there are zero requirements about format and contents of these data, right? "User" does not need specific fields, does not want to convert it into anything, no search needs, correct? Is there any chance that user wants something specific from the request?

Comment: First off, the `serializers` class is in `django.core` not `rest_framework`.  However, when serializing a WsgiRequest, I only get an empty dictionary back as `[]`.

Comment: Second, when passing the `request` to context as a value of a JSON Object, then it displays ```<WSGIRequest: GET '/myapp/api/mymethod'>```

Comment: I know there is a way to recursively serialize JSON because I did it before in an AWS Lamdba Function, but I don't have the code for it to reference and need to research this more.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced similar problem when trying to store received requests META data in JSONField. Problem is that `request.META` is a dict but it's not appropriate JSON.

Example request.META I have is:

```
{
   "wsgi.version": (1, 0), 
   "wsgi.url_scheme": "http", 
   "wsgi.input": <_io.BufferedReader name=10>, 
   "wsgi.errors": <_io.TextIOWrapper name="<stderr>" mode="w" encoding="utf-8">,
   "wsgi.multithread": True, 
   "wsgi.multiprocess": False, 
   "wsgi.run_once": False, 
   "SERVER_SOFTWARE": "Werkzeug/1.0.1", 
   "REQUEST_METHOD": "POST", 
   "SCRIPT_NAME": "", 
   "PATH_INFO": "/api/v1/vouchers/voucher-distribute/", 
   "QUERY_STRING": "", 
   "REQUEST_URI": "/api/v1/vouchers/voucher-distribute"
...
}
```

So as you can see first few keys with `wsgi` prefix is inappropriate JSON format what you can also check online at: http://json.parser.online.fr/

So to store request.META as JSON dict it's necessary to get rid of this keys. The trick is that you cannot use request.META.pop("wsgi.version") because request.META is not appropriate JSON format :)

What I did is I've created helper function:

```
def create_request_meta_json_object(meta_data):
    return {
        "REQUEST_METHOD": meta_data["REQUEST_METHOD"],
        "SERVER_SOFTWARE": meta_data["SERVER_SOFTWARE"],
        "REQUEST_METHOD": meta_data["REQUEST_METHOD"],
        "SCRIPT_NAME": meta_data["SCRIPT_NAME"],
        "PATH_INFO": meta_data["PATH_INFO"],
        "QUERY_STRING": meta_data["QUERY_STRING"],
        "REQUEST_URI": meta_data["REQUEST_URI"],
        "RAW_URI": meta_data["RAW_URI"],
        "REMOTE_ADDR": meta_data["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        "REMOTE_PORT": meta_data["REMOTE_PORT"],
        "SERVER_NAME": meta_data["SERVER_NAME"],
        "SERVER_PORT": meta_data["SERVER_PORT"],
        "SERVER_PROTOCOL": meta_data["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],
        "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST": meta_data["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST"],
        "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT": meta_data["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT"],
        "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING": meta_data["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"],
        "HTTP_USER_AGENT": meta_data["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],
        "HTTP_FROM": meta_data["HTTP_FROM"],
        "HTTP_ACCEPT": meta_data["HTTP_ACCEPT"],
        "CONTENT_TYPE": meta_data["CONTENT_TYPE"],
        "CONTENT_LENGTH": meta_data["CONTENT_LENGTH"],
        "HTTP_CONNECTION": meta_data["HTTP_CONNECTION"],
        "HTTP_X_NGINX_PROXY": meta_data["HTTP_X_NGINX_PROXY"],
        "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO": meta_data["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"],
        "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR": meta_data["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"],
        "HTTP_X_REAL_IP": meta_data["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"],
    }
```

and use it like:

```
meta_data_as_json = create_request_meta_json_object(request.META)
```

Comment: how about a dictionary comprehension:

Comment: simplify `return {key: value for key, value in meta_data.items()}`

Comment: Ideally, shouldn't the serialization be recursive to convert objects within object instead of stopping at the top?

Comment: I like the concept.  However, it is missing the payload of the POST request which likely is in one of two parts which were dropped.  Also, shouldn't this create a 'WSGIRequest' JSON Object which identifies the 'headers', 'body', and 'uri' separately for serialization?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot serialize `request` - you could serialize `request.GET` also know as `request.query_params`in DRF.

```
srd = json.dumps(request.query_params)
```

or

```
srd = json.dumps(request.GET)
```

To use a serializer, you first have to create one. [Declaring Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#declaring-serializers) is a good starting point.

Another potential solution is to use dictionary comprehension:

```
meta_keys = {
   "wsgi.version": (1, 0), 
   "wsgi.version": "http", 
   "wsgi.input": object(), 
   "wsgi.errors": object(),
   "wsgi.multithread": True, 
   "wsgi.multiprocess": False, 
   "wsgi.run_once": False, 
   "SERVER_SOFTWARE": "Werkzeug/1.0.1", 
   "REQUEST_METHOD": "POST", 
   "SCRIPT_NAME": "", 
   "PATH_INFO": "/api/v1/vouchers/voucher-distribute/", 
   "QUERY_STRING": "", 
   "REQUEST_URI": "/api/v1/vouchers/voucher-distribute"
}

excluded_meta_keys = ['wsgi.version', 'wsgi.version', 'wsgi.input', 'wsgi.multithread', 'wsgi.multiprocess', 'wsgi.run_once', 'wsgi.errors']

print({key: value for key, value in meta_keys.items() if key not in excluded_meta_keys})

print({key: value for key, value in meta_keys.items() if isinstance(value, (str, bool, int, float))})
```

results in:

```
{'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Werkzeug/1.0.1', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'PATH_INFO': '/api/v1/vouchers/voucher-distribute/', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'REQUEST_URI': '/api/v1/vouchers/voucher-distribute'}

{'wsgi.version': 'http', 'wsgi.multithread': True, 'wsgi.multiprocess': False, 'wsgi.run_once': False, 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Werkzeug/1.0.1', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'PATH_INFO': '/api/v1/vouchers/voucher-distribute/', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'REQUEST_URI': '/api/v1/vouchers/voucher-distribute'}
```

respectively

Comment: What about `request.META`?

Comment: what about `request.META`? what is your question?

Comment: I like this concept too, but also it drops the object recursion to extract the POST Body from the Request which is essential for POST logging.  Now since POST Logging can be lengthy, the size of the POST Body could be captured and a clip of the POST body could be returned or logged?  (The reason I say this is when the POST body is an octet-stream of 500 MB to 100 GB of data streamed.)

Answer (score 0):

request.META has keys of types not allowed by a json object, so you can generate another dictionary only with keys with values of str type:

```
dict = create_request_meta_json_object(request.META)

def create_request_meta_json_object(meta_data):
    diccionario = []
    for key, value in meta_data.items():
        if type(value) is str:
            diccionario.append({"key": key, "value": value})
    return diccionario
```

Answer (score 0):

While this does not handle the "WSGIRequest", here is how I handled the exception handling when the code to serialize the object fails so it is easier to fix it.

I'll post an update to this answer for the serializing of the "WSGIRequest" object to explain why I would return a different format:

```
except Exception as error:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_context = sys.exc_info()

    sExceptionName = str(exc_type.__name__)
    sExceptionReason = str(exc_value)
    sExceptionTraceback = str(traceback.format_exception(exc_context))

    rHttpResponse = JsonResponse( 
        {
            "status": "error",
            "exception": {
                "name": sExceptionName,
                "reason": sExceptionReason,
                "traceback": sExceptionTraceback 
            }
        }
    )

return rHttpResponse
```

The goal being where any Exception is serialized to the actual Exception in a recognizable form.

The end result is something a caller can determine how much to show to give the user some smart error message to capture and send to a help desk.